CP-SAT | OR-Tools: at most one of two different arrays (OR-ed). How to declare constraint?
I have two arrays of model variables - arr1 and arr2. I would like to declare a constraint that would forbid a situation when there is at least 1 true in arr1 AND at least 1 true in arr2. (There can be multiple true's in arr1, as long as arr2 has only false's - and vice versa. It is also acceptable if there is no true in neither array).
So, something like that:
arr1 = [model.new_bool_var("a"), model.new_bool_var("b"), ...]
arr2 = [model.new_bool_var("q"), model.new_bool_var("w"), ...]

model.add_at_most_one(bool_or(arr1), bool_or(arr2))

Hower, such syntax doesn't exist - there is only add_bool_or() method, not generic bool_or() that could serve to build inner clauses for more complex constraints.
Therefore, I thought about taking the following approach:
sum_arr1 = model.new_int_var(0, len(arr1), "sum_arr1")
sum_arr2 = model.new_int_var(0, len(arr2), "sum_arr2")
model.add(sum_arr1 == sum(arr1))
model.add(sum_arr2 == sum(arr2))
arr1_at_least_one = model.new_bool_var("arr1_at_least_one")
arr2_at_least_one = model.new_bool_var("arr2_at_least_one")
model.add(sum_arr1 > 0).only_enforce_if(arr1_at_least_one)  # channeling constraints
model.add(sum_arr1 == 0).only_enforce_if(~arr1_at_least_one)
model.add(sum_arr2 > 0).only_enforce_if(arr2_at_least_one)
model.add(sum_arr2 == 0).only_enforce_if(~arr2_at_least_one)
model.add_at_most_one(arr1_at_least_one, arr2_at_least_one)

This seems to be working (I initially had a silly typo in my code). Still, I am wondering if it is possible to declare the same constraint in a simpler way, in particular - without using integer (non-boolean) variables...?
Could you help me declare such constraint?
In other words, it is NAND(OR(arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], ...), OR(arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2], ...))
Perhaps something like this will do?
arr1_at_least_one = model.new_bool_var("arr1_at_least_one")
arr2_at_least_one = model.new_bool_var("arr2_at_least_one")
for i in arr1:
    model.add_implication(i, arr1_at_least_one)
model.add_at_least_one(arr1).only_enforce_if(arr1_at_least_one)
for j in arr2:
    model.add_implication(j, arr2_at_least_one)
model.add_at_least_one(arr2).only_enforce_if(arr2_at_least_one)
model.add_at_most_one(arr1_at_least_one, arr2_at_least_one)


you just need to create the bool var arrays correctly.
What is the semantics of ... ? What is the length of the array. The model needs to be grounded when passed to the solver.
The rest of the code is OK.

Silly me, I left the ... in the code for the purpose of asking this question (the example was supposed to be in meta code :)

You are almost there. Just need to work with ad hoc variables that represent the conditions (i.e. at least one variable in array is True).
arr1 = [model.new_bool_var(f"a1{i}") for i in range(3)]
arr2 = [model.new_bool_var(f"a2{i}") for i in range(3)]

arr1_true = model.new_bool_var("a1t")  # (1)
arr2_true = model.new_bool_var("a2t")

model.Add(sum(arr1) >= 1).only_enforce_if(arr1_true)  # (2)
model.Add(sum(arr1) == 0).only_enforce_if(arr2_true)  # (3)

model.Add(sum(arr2) >= 1).only_enforce_if(arr2_true)
model.Add(sum(arr2) == 0).only_enforce_if(arr1_true)

The logic is to

create ad hoc bool to represent that arr1 has at least one True
set bool arr1_true to True if arr1 has at least one True
set bools in arr1 to False if arr2_true is True (arr2 has at least one True)

And vice versa.
